# How to make sql table display age computed by a specific formula?

Tags: php, mysql

The formula:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, `date_of_birth`, CURDATE())
```

I have to manually execute this query:

```
UPDATE `squad` SET `age` = TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, `date_of_birth`, CURDATE())
```

Every time I insert rows into table, also when there is a player's birthday it surely doesn't apply a new age.

Comment: Not clear what you are really asking

Comment: What have you trīed?

Comment: @tereško To make age default value "As defined" and apply formula there, also in php I tried this if(substr($row["date_of_birth"],5,2)==date("m") && substr($row["date_of_birth"],-2)==date("d")) "If a player has birthday" ++$row["age"]

Comment: It's better to store the date of birth and to calculate the age when you wish to display it, than to store the age in a table. In less than a year's time your column will become wrong.

Comment: @Dima_736 the next time show it in your question. It will earn you a lot less downvotes that way. The issue that you are looking at comes from fact that while `DATE` **looks** like a string in MySQL results, it is **not a string**. If you are storing date of birth as varchar (which is your first mistake), trhen you should be using `STR_TO_DATE('2001-05-21', '%Y-%m-%d')` to turn it into a `DATE`

Comment: @tereško Oh tnx, just hit the enter by accident before finishing and it all started from that... First, date_of_birth is the Date datatype not Varchar

Answer (score 0):

Please make ensure that ,are you use datetime or date  data type  for  `date_of_birth` in  your table(not var char data type),if so then its working fine. and one more thing  insert  `date_of_birth` as Y-m-d format. For your doubt i create same table and run same query then its working fine[image]